# Why $(x-2)^2$ cannot be divided by $(x-2)(x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the question may seem ridiculous. My question is:

> Why can't $(x-2)^2$ be divided by $(x-2)(x-3)$?

I know the answer is obvious if we do the division by hand. However, we also know that if remainder of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is zero, then $Q(x)$ is a divisor of $P(x)$.

Notice that:
$$(x-2)^2 = (x-3)(x-2)Q(x) + R(x).$$ If x =2 then 
$$(2-2)^2 = (2-3)(2-2)Q(x) + R(x) \to R(x) = 0,$$ so $(x-2)^2$ can be divided by $(x-2)(x-3)$.

This happens because $R(x) = ax +b$, and it isn't a single number, like $b$. Is there is another reason for it?

Thanks.

Comment: if $p(x)$ divides $q(x)$ then $p(a)=0\implies q(a)=0$.  Now take $a=3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not deduce that $R(x)=0$. Only that $R(2)=0$ (you forgot to substitute this $x$).

Answer (score 0):

$(x-2)(x-2)/(x-2)(x-3)=(x-2)/(x-3)$ which is clear. This shows that for all x not equal to 2 that there will indeed be a remainder.

Comment: This equality only holds for $x\neq 2$.  It's true that your suggestion simplifies the problem, but a bit more explanation of how one gets the conclusion would help many Readers.

Answer (score 0):

Let us have a polynomial $f(X)$. I claim that $X-a$ divides $f$ if and only if $a$ is a root of $f$.

From Euclidean division, we get that $f(X) = q(X)(X-a) + r(X)$, where $\deg r <\deg (X-a) = 1$ or $r = 0$.

Assume that $X-a$ divides $f$. Then $r = 0$, and $f(a)=q(a)(a-a) = 0$.

Now assume that $a$ is root of $f$. Then $0 = f(a) = q(a)(a-a)+r = r$, so $X-a$ divides $f$.

Now, $X-3$ does not divide $(X-2)^2$ since $(3-2)^2 \neq 0$, so $(X-3)(X-1)$ can't divide it either.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide $(x-2)^2$ with $(x-2)(x-3)$ you get $\frac{(x-2)}{(x-3)}$. The polynomial $q(x)$ divides the polynomial $p(x)$ if there  exist a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $p(x) = g(x)\times q(x)$. You have that $\frac{(x-2)}{(x-3)} = \frac{1}{x-3} + 1$.